Laptop shuts down a few seconds after booting (not a power issue)
I recently received an old acer aspire 8920G laptop.
Processor: Intel centrino Core 2 Duo T8300 2 x 2.4GHz
Graphics card: NVIDIA GeForce 9650M GS - 512 MB
Memory: 4 GB DDR2
Display: 18.40 inch 16:9, 1920 x 1080 pixel, Full HD
Mainboard: Intel PM965
HDD: 320 GB - WDC WD3200BEVT
The problem with this device is that it turns off a few seconds after I turn it on, but the timing is not always consistent. Sometimes it reaches windows loading screen, others it turns off almost immediately.
At first I thought it was a power issue but the laptop runs both only with a charger and also only with the battery. Furthermore, if I access BIOS it stays on indefinitely.
I tried booting Linux from a live usb, but the problem was the same.
It could possibly be an overheating problem, but I don't feel the laptop warming up at all and the CPU fan is clean. Otherwise could this be caused by a faulty CPU or motherboard?
Any ideas what I could try?
Thank you in advance

The Problem is in Hardware. Needs to be disassembled and checked one by one.

I was hoping I could narrow it down a bit. When you say check it one by one, by what method by you mean? Like remove all unnecessary components and trying booting? Do you know any diagnostic tool I could use?

Clean dirt, check processor paste, try using an external keyboard. If still, you need special expertise in the field of motherboard hardware to check it using a Power Supply and MultiTester. (google translate)

I checked the interior and its very clean. CPU paste is a problem I considered, but I never had to replace it in any computer I ever had, even if it was many years old. Maybe the motherboard is short-circuiting but I don't see any such sign (visual, audible, or smell)

If the paste is dry, it is no longer working. Must be replaced or added new

@Mr.Key7, the last thing to do is change thermal paste. 1. A low-power CPU does not overheat immediately after turning on. 2. It does not overheat in in BIOS, when left on indefinitely. 3. Trying to remove the cooler and to reapply paste can damage the CPU and motherboard.

@OdysseasLienor, look to loose RAM and connectors (remove and put back), dead clock cell (fairly easily replaced; measure and replace), or bad electrolytic capacitor (can be replaced by someone with technical experience) -- see https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/244671/laptop+resetting+during+install

@DrMoishePippik Wow, that link seems very helpful. I already fidgeted with RAM, but it didn't fix the problem. I have disassembled the CPU AND GPU cooler and tomorrow I will purchase some paste to replace the old one, just to be sure. The capacitor seems waaaay to difficult to change, at least for my abilities, but from the description it seems to be the problem. From what I read, disabling one CPU core also seems to solve the problem. I will try it once I get the laptop running again. Thank you very much.

@OdysseasLienor, as mentioned, I'd avoid changing thermal compound unless the PC has known overheating issues. Glad you got it working with one core, though!

@DrMoishePippik Too late, I already removed the paste. I haven't tried disabling one core yet, but from what I read, it will do the trick. Still, working with just one core will be less than ideal, but it's better than nothing
